# haskell strange type error when using point-free notation with (.) operator

Tags: haskell, typeerror

Can someone please explain to me why this code doesn't work:

```haskell
import GHC.Exts (build)
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)

toLambdaList :: List t0 -> (t0 -> t1 -> t1) -> t1 -> t1
toLambdaList Nil cons nil = nil
toLambdaList (x `Cons` xs) cons nil = x `cons` (toLambdaList xs cons nil)
fromList :: List a -> [a]
fromList = build . toLambdaList
```

the error I'm getting is this:

```haskell
Couldn't match type: forall b. (a -> b -> b) -> b -> b
               with: (t1 -> t20 -> t20) -> t20 -> t20
```

(GHCi version 9.0.2)

Suprisingly, if I just replace `build . toLambdaList` with `\a -> build $ toLambdaList a`, the new code suddenly works:

```haskell
import GHC.Exts (build)
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)

toLambdaList :: List t0 -> (t0 -> t1 -> t1) -> t1 -> t1
toLambdaList Nil cons nil = nil
toLambdaList (x `Cons` xs) cons nil = x `cons` (toLambdaList xs cons nil)
fromList :: List a -> [a]
fromList a = build $ toLambdaList a
```

I've tried deleting type declarations, but this doesn't help.

Comment: This is because the `(.)` "drops" the `forall`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why this doesn't work (since GHC 9) is that `forall` is treated more literally now in types. In your case the types

In your case the compiler complains that it cannot match these types:

```
   Expected: ((a -> t1 -> t1) -> t1 -> t1) -> [a]
     Actual: (forall b. (a -> b -> b) -> b -> b) -> [a]
```

They do look different, but you may expect that GHC would just instantiate that `forall b` in the actual type to `t1`. Then the types would match. That is what GHC used to do before version 9 and can now be re-enabled with a new extension called `DeepSubsumption` in GHC 9.2 and later.

GHC does still instantiate `forall`'d variables in some cases, but not when it is below the left side of a function arrow such as in your case.

The main reasons for making this change were:

- It simplifies the type checker.
- It makes it possible to support impredicative types properly.
- These instantiations would silently affect runtime behavior.

For more details see the [Simplify Subsumption proposal](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0287-simplify-subsumption.rst).

One way you can solve this is by using [`ImpredicativeTypes`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.6.2/docs/users_guide/exts/impredicative_types.html) (which can be a replacement for deep subsumption in some cases) and changing the type of `toLambdaList` a little:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImpredicativeTypes #-}

import GHC.Exts (build)
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)

toLambdaList :: List t0 -> forall t1. (t0 -> t1 -> t1) -> t1 -> t1
toLambdaList Nil cons nil = nil
toLambdaList (x `Cons` xs) cons nil = x `cons` (toLambdaList xs cons nil)
fromList :: List a -> [a]
fromList = build . toLambdaList
```

To understand why this works we need to look at the type of `(.)`:

```
(.) :: forall a b c. (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

Using `ImpredicativeTypes` we can instantiate `b` to be `forall t1. (t0 -> t1 -> t1) -> t1 -> t1`. And `a` and `b` are instantiated as usual to `List a` and `[a]` respectively. The specialised type of `(.)` then becomes:

```
(.) :: forall a t0.
  ((forall t1. (t0 -> t1 -> t1) -> t1 -> t1) -> [a]) ->
  (List a -> forall t1. (t0 -> t1 -> t1) -> t1 -> t1) ->
  List a -> [a]
```

Now the type of the first argument matches the type of `build` and the type of the second argument matches the type of `toLambdaList`.